# add html tag inside sql query result

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I am using oracle 11g, I have a sql query that returns a string type result_column with the following formatting of text (it's a concatenation obtained via the listagg function) :

aaa, bbbbbbb, cc, dddddddddd

I dont know the number of "operands", it can be 2, 3, 4 or even more...

I want to HTML format the result in order to alternate colors, so i want to transform the result column into :

```
<font color="red">aaa,</font> <font color="green">bbbbbbb,</font> <font      color="red">cc,</font> <font color="green">dddddddddd</font>
```

is this possible ? (via regular expressions maybe ?)

In advance thank you very much for any tip you might give

Kind regards
Jam

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. (The answer may be product specific.)

Comment: done thank you! it's oracle 11g

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way, although it's quite clunky (it needs both a regexp_replace and a normal replace):

```
WITH sample_data AS (SELECT 'aaa, bbbbbbb, cc, dddddddddd' str FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 'aaa' str FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 'aaaa, bbbbbbb' str FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 'aa, bbbbbb, ccc' str FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 'aaaa, b, ccc, dddd' str FROM dual)
SELECT str,
       replace(regexp_replace(str, 
                              '( ?)([^,]+)(,|$) ?([^,]*)(,|$)',
                              '\1<font color="red">\2\3</font> <font color="green">\4\5</font>'),
               '<font color="green"></font>') new_str
FROM   sample_data;

STR                          NEW_STR
---------------------------- ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
aaa, bbbbbbb, cc, dddddddddd <font color="red">aaa,</font> <font color="green">bbbbbbb,</font> <font color="red">cc,</font> <font color="green">dddddddddd</font>
aaa                          <font color="red">aaa</font>
aaaa, bbbbbbb                <font color="red">aaaa,</font> <font color="green">bbbbbbb</font>
aa, bbbbbb, ccc              <font color="red">aa,</font> <font color="green">bbbbbb,</font> <font color="red">ccc</font>
aaaa, b, ccc, dddd           <font color="red">aaaa,</font> <font color="green">b,</font> <font color="red">ccc,</font> <font color="green">dddd</font>
```

Basically, this searches for the pattern where we have 0 or 1 spaces followed by any number of non-comma characters, followed by either a comma or the end of the line. This could then be followed by a similar pattern, or not (hence the * in the second half of the regexp pattern, vs the + in the first half) since we might have an odd number of elements in the string.

Then it does the replace, using the elements in the brackets in the search pattern (each bracketed element can be referred to by \N, where N is its occurrence in the pattern string) in the relevant places.

Finally, to take account of the fact that odd elements will leave a trailing `<font color="green"></font>`, we need to strip that off - hence the outer `replace`.

I'd be willing to bet that there are more efficient solutions than this, however!

Comment: Thank you very much Boneist! that worked like a charm + nice explanation, i was able to play a little bit with the regexp_replace function, thanks again !

Answer (score 0):

In theory it can be done quite simply if the number of values are finite, say a maximum of 10. It isn't pretty (in fact, it's quite ugly ;), but it works. Replace

```
([^,]*,?)?([^,]*,?)?([^,]*,?)?([^,]*,?)?([^,]*,?)?([^,]*,?)?([^,]*,?)?([^,]*,?)?([^,]*,?)?([^,]*,?)?
```

with

```
<font color="red">\1</font> <font color="green">\2</font> <font color="red">\3</font> <font color="green">\4</font> <font color="red">\5</font> <font color="green">\6</font> <font color="red">\7</font> <font color="green">\8</font> <font color="red">\9</font> <font color="green">\10</font>
```

[See it here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/bK7iK7/2).

And a javascript snippet to illustrate.

```js
var regex = /([^,]*,?)?([^,]*,?)?([^,]*,?)?([^,]*,?)?([^,]*,?)?([^,]*,?)?([^,]*,?)?([^,]*,?)?([^,]*,?)?([^,]*,?)?/,
    repl = '<font color="red">$1</font> <font color="green">$2</font> <font color="red">$3</font> <font color="green">$4</font> <font color="red">$5</font> <font color="green">$6</font> <font color="red">$7</font> <font color="green">$8</font> <font color="red">$9</font> <font color="green">$10</font>',
    input = 'aaa, bbbbbbb, cc, dddddddddd';

document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = input.replace(regex, repl);
```

```html
<div id="output"/>
```